# Reduction CVP to CFG problem

Tags: context-free, reductions

I want to show that non-emptiness of context free language is P-complete. So, I am trying to reduce CVP to this problem by generating grammar from circuit. I consider all type of gates in circuit and I make right production in grammar.

I hope that it is good way to prove that it is P-complete, but I have a problem with showing that it is log-space reduction. I think that if I have this circuit, I need only one pointer to the structure, because I can directly write the production. Howerver, I need also have information how the non-terminal symbol is named. Of course, I can use binary numbers for variable names (and it is log-space), but it seems to me that I need know all names to produce grammar production. I have no idea how to go in this graph (circuit) and give a names of next non-terminals and use only log-space.

Could anyone explain me how to prove that it is log-space reduction?

Comment: Ok, I suppose that I know an answer. :) It can be done by moving from output to inputs and giving left child of node number 2*i and the right child - 2*i+1. And now we can always reconstruct these numbers.

Comment: Now I have another problem. How to prove that grammar generates at most one string iff the output of circuit on given evaluation is true?